# What do spikes in InnoDB lock structures indicate?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I co-maintain a high traffic site similar to StackExchange. It runs MySQL 5.1 (working on replacing it with MySQL 5.5 or MariaDB). All our tables are InnoDB. MySQL goes down a couple of times a day. By that I mean that queries start timing out and the site goes down accordingly.

When this happens, and I have 'mtop' open, I can see queries queueing up trying to do INSERTs on tables with only 60.000 or so rows. There's only a few indexes on such tables, all integers.

In our MonitorIX MySQL graphs, supplied by a Percona package, I see spikes in a 'InnoDB lock structures' that correspond with the downtimes:

[image: InnoDB lock structures graph]

Another corresponding phenomenon is a spike in queries that reside in state Statistics:

[image: MySQL process list graph]

What exactly is happening when a database shows spikes in amount of lock structures and queries in state Statistics? Where do I need to start looking to overcome these outages?

Aside from these incidental outages, our site performs fine.

Comment: Are you sure a backup or some other scheduled task isn't happening at the same time as your spikes?

Comment: There is indeed a crontab with a bunch of background tasks that talk to the database. But not one that runs at only and precisely the times at which the spikes occur.

Comment: Some explanation as to what spikes in lock structures could stand for, would help me explain what's going on.

Comment: Download the free version of Jet Profile http://www.jetprofiler.com/download/, it will store the information for later viewing so you can keep it running overnight. Might shed some more light on what's causing the increased locking

Comment: I would look at SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS when you see the spike. The high 'InnoDB lock structures' means InnoDB transactions keep many locks. The question - why. This may be either some long running transactions or normally short transactions are affected by other jobs (e.g. storm flushing). Anyway, check SHOW INNODB STATUS

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's a hosted machine on which I am a developer type of user. I have requested privileges to show InnoDB status. I will also try to more closely monitor database load coming from the crontab.